# FLINT lib: how to delete a polynomial

Tags: c++, memory-management, flint

In the library [FLINT](http://www.flintlib.org/), we have the function *fmpz_poly_clear* to clear a *fmpz_poly* polynomial from the memory. But I am using the C++ interface of this library, so, my polynomials are of the type *fmpz_polyxx* or *fmpz_mod_polyxx*.

I would like to know how to clear these polynomials. I already searched on the FLINT's documentation, but I found nothing.

For instance, the following program creates a polynomial with seven million coefficients. On my machine, it uses about 1GB of RAM. After exiting the for loop, I try to delete the polynomial.

I am reading a integer after just to make the program wait before terminating the execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "flint/fmpzxx.h"
#include "flint/fmpz_mod_polyxx.h"
#include "flint/fmpz_mod_poly_factorxx.h"

using namespace flint;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // q  (273-bit prime)
    fmpzxx q("15177100720513508366558296147058741458143803430094840009779784451085189728165691397");

    fmpz_mod_polyxx* myPoly = new fmpz_mod_polyxx(q); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 7000000; i++){
        myPoly->set_coeff(i, q - fmpzxx(i));
    }
    delete myPoly;             // <-- this line does not work
//  fmpz_poly_clear(myPoly);  // <-- this line does not work
//  fmpz_mod_polyxx_clear(myPoly); // <-- this one neither
    int a;
    std::cin >> a; // wait 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `flint` to work with polynomials, it is best to work with `fmpz_mod_poly_t` instead of `* fmpz_mod_poly`. The type `fmpz_mod_poly_t` is typedefed to an array of length 1 of `fmpz_mod_poly_struct`, so it behaves similar to pointers and allows passing parameters of type `fmpz_mod_poly_struct` by reference.

(This pattern is held throughout `flint`, `arb`, `calcium`, and the other libraries in the same family). The `init` and `clear` functions expect these types and will do it appropriately.

For example, this smaller code initializes a polynomial, squares it, prints it, and then clears the memory for both the polynomials and the modulus.

```cpp
#include "fmpz_mod_poly.h"
int main() {
  fmpz_t n;                // array of length 1 fmpz_struct
  fmpz_mod_poly_t x, y;    // array of length 1 fmpz_mod_poly_struct

  fmpz_init_set_ui(n, 7);  // n = 7
  fmpz_mod_poly_init(x, n);
  fmpz_mod_poly_init(y, n);
  fmpz_mod_poly_set_coeff_ui(x, 3, 5);
  fmpz_mod_poly_set_coeff_ui(x, 0, 6);
  fmpz_mod_poly_sqr(y, x);
  fmpz_mod_poly_print(x); flint_printf("\n");
  fmpz_mod_poly_print(y); flint_printf("\n");

  fmpz_mod_poly_clear(x); // clear x memory
  fmpz_mod_poly_clear(y); // clear y memory
  fmpz_clear(n);          // clear modulus memory
}
```

Internally, each `fmpz_mod_poly_struct` consists of several coefficients, each of which is an `fmpz` integer. On creation and with manipulation, these might be allocated and changed. On deletion, each of these need to be cleared as well, which is why simply calling `delete` on `*fmpz_mod_poly` won't work. Instead, that will cause memory leaks.

Comment: So do you think there is no way to do that when one uses the C++ interface?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira In principle, the C++ interface would work as you'd noted. But it's brittle and unmaintained (now there is no C++ dev working on it). I looked through the code to see if I could track the problem. It might be that `fmpz_mod_polyxx` refers to a `fmpz_modxx_ctx` to delete... but it seems this isn't actually necessary to construct the polynomial? Dragons lie that way.